# Removing specific rows in an input .txt file (python)

Tags: python, io

I want to do some manipulations on an input .txt file from this:

```
A 0.4
B 0.1
C 0.3
_ 0.2
_ 0.7
D 0.9
```

into this:

```
A 0.4
B 0.1
C 0.3
D 0.9
```

In other words, get rid of the rows with the underscore symbol.

What first comes to my mind is making a dictionary and then deleting the "_" values. But the problem with the dictionary is that it messes the order of the elements. How can I approach this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a check to see if the line starts with an "_". if it does skip that line from writing.

```
with open("Path_to_txt", 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()

with open("Path_to_txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for i in data:
        if not i.startswith("_"):
            outfile.write(i)
```